# Syntax Error in Users#show with If statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, erb

So I have this ERB partial that renders a different partial depending on the passed local parameter:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) do %>
    <div id="relation">
        <% if current_user.friends?(@user) %>
            <%= render('edit-relation', locals: { action: "rm-friend" })%>
        <% elsif current_user.req_friends?(@user) %>
            Friend Request Pending...
        <% elsif current_user.pend_friends?(@user) %>
            <%= render('edit-relation', locals: { action: "add-friend" })%>
            <%= render('edit-relation', locals: { action: "rej-friend" })%>
        <% else %>
            <%= render('edit-relation', locals: { action: "req-friend" })%>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

It throws Syntax errors:

```
Showing C:/Users/HP/Ubuntu One/A2 Computing Project/Software Development/Client/app/views/layouts/_relation.html.erb where line #15 raised:

C:/Users/HP/Ubuntu One/A2 Computing Project/Software Development/Client/app/views/layouts/_relation.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
C:/Users/HP/Ubuntu One/A2 Computing Project/Software Development/Client/app/views/layouts/_relation.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

There is no line 15 or 17. Does anyone see what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if current_user
```

You can't do that in ruby. There's a special keyword for this, `elsif`.

```
if a
  # ...
elsif b
  # ...
elsif c
  # ...
else
  # ...
end
```

### Also

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) do %>
```

Remove the `do` here.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:turns out you cant use `unless` like that, I changed it to an If statement instead

Comment: That's what I told you. You can't `unless ... do`

Comment: Sorry about that, after I commented last time, i didn't look at the question again until i answered it myself, and I didn't see your edit (I didn't refresh the page. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Oh, also removing the `do` didn't actually work, I tried that and it still threw the same error. I had to change it completely.

Comment: I thought so too,but I don't want to dwell on it right now since my project is due Tuesday. Thanks for your help:)